# how to change my wordpress homepage title, description and image on facebook

Tags: wordpress

I build a new wordpress site and installed the Yoast SEO plugin.

My homepage defined as some of my pages.

When i post the link on facebook i can't see any description/title/image that i want

checked on - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
i got:
og:type     article
(i think that In order to work should appear : website)

maybe someone knows Where I'm wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses OpenGraph, a protocol for which if no default values are defined (and you have no standard HTML `<meta>` values defined,) you can set certain properties so that your site will appear as you want it when you share it socially.

It should be noted that Opengraph will, by default, attempt to interpret these properties by their corresponding `<meta>` elements (stuff like `<meta name="description" content="describe my site">`).

If you don't have these, I suggest you add them, but the OpenGraph properties can be defined explicitly, too. The process for adding properties like this involve the use of the `<meta>` tag, typically in your `header.php`.

[There are a lot of properties you can define](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object)

I think most pertinent to your situation would be:

`<meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image">`

`<meta property="og:title" content="My cool website">`

`<meta property="og:description" content="Description of site">`

These work for sites that use OpenGraph, but it's no substitute for having proper `<meta>` tags in the `<head>` of your document.

[here's a bit of reading you can do on defining site meta](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2067564/How-To-Use-HTML-Meta-Tags)

Hope this helps!